# sbt failure for java.sql.{Connector,DriverManager,ResultSet}

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am running into an issue when I run "sbt package" on a scala program. Here are the imports that I have in my scala program

```
import java.sql.{Connecion,DriverManager,ResultSet}
```

when I run sbt package, I get the below errors.

```
[error] /home/SriniNN/scala_cd/ReadDJDBC/src/main/scala/ReadDJDBC.scala:8: object Connecion is not a member of package java.sql
[error] import java.sql.{Connecion,DriverManager,ResultSet}
[error]        ^
[error] /home/SriniNN/scala_cd/ReadDJDBC/src/main/scala/ReadDJDBC.scala:26: value getConnecion is not a member of object java.sql.DriverManager
[error] val jdbcRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, () => DriverManager.getConnecion(url,username,password),
```

This is what I have in my build.sbt

```
name:= "ReadJDBC"
version:= "1.0"
scalaVersion:= "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2"
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: `Connecion` should be`Connection`

Answer (score 0):

You are just mis-spelling Connec**t**ion. Note the t between the c and i. If you fix that typo then it should work

Comment: Good catch.. :). Thank you very much. That solved my issue.